# Using MVVM with ntier and Service Based architecture

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, n-tier-architecture

I know this question might not be up to the standards of StackOverflow. But I am getting hard time finding the solution.
My current application is service based (web api 2) which is using ntier architecture to communicate.
On server side I am using `Entity Framework` for Model generation from the Database.

This is the flow of my app right now:

```
Client:
WPF UI + DTO -> BLL -> Service Call Layer

Server:
Web Api Controller -> BLL + DTO -> DAL + DTO
```

So how should I integrate MVVM so that I can bind properly and get INotify also.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean how to integrate MVVM. MVVM comes in between you UI (WPF) layer and BLL. You write you Views (V) and bind the view with ViewModels (VM) and the M is your Model which you are basically accessing via your service layer.

Comment: Why don't you rough out a very simple prototype and come back to us if you have any issues.